# How can I solve Server error! Error 500 when running app in xampp

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I'm working on a website using codeigniter framework. I pasted all the package to phpdesktop because we were trying to convert it to desktop application which worked well. But when I move the folder to **htdocs** in xamp it failed to run, giving the below error:

Server error!

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 500 localhost
>       Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.3.5

when I checked apache error log, I have this displayed:

> [Fri May 10 18:36:37.353885 2019] [core:alert] [pid 14880:tid 1912]
>   [client ::1:58528] C:/xampp/htdocs/law/.htaccess: Invalid command
>   '//', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the
>   server configuration

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sys_info/$1 [L]
```

How can I resolve it. It worked perfectly in phpdesktop in addition.

Answer (score 0):

have you configured your `index_page` on `config.php` already? I you just leave it blank, here's a sample of ***.htaccess*** that's working for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Check again file `C:\xampp\htdocs\law\.htaccess` -- it seems to have some line like `// this is a comment` but it should be `# this is a comment`